# Identify anime robot show from 80s/ early 90s, song sounds like Silver Surfer?

Tags: identify-this-movie, identify-this-tv-show, anime

Okay, I'm getting insane from this. I have this theme song from my childhood stuck in my head and vague memories of anime movie/tv show. Theme song goes something like this and I remember only refrain:

Silver Surfer(?) and ***something something***

Silver Surfer and ***something something*** in disguise. [**gunshot sound effect**]

*more lyrics then*

Silver Surfer(?) and ***something something***

Silver Surfer and ***something something*** in disguise. [**gunshot sound effect**]

[repeats over and over, although there are more lyrics I can't remember them except for refrain, which is VERY annoying. Help!]

Vague memories include transforming cars (It is not Transformers! I know they have robots in disguise as opening lyrics, but this is not it), some blond girl, some guy with blue cowboy hat who is shooting at the camera and another who rides a motorcycle I think? He is wearing red. I think they ride cars which transform into giant robot (robot is also wearing a cowboy hat, maybe), but I am not certain. The girl might be wearing a pink suit, like Kimberly in Power Rangers. Can anyone help me please?

Edit: Thanks for jiggling my memory with Silver Hawks, JRCharney. I think that they were all transforming into battle suits like power rangers. The girl was wearing pink tracksuit with helmet, one of the guys was wearing red and the cowboy was wearing blue one. They had the seethrough visors of the same color and cars had huge colored wind-shields.

Edit2: Thanks a lot, Leon. It was Saber Rider! Turns out that the real lyrics are:

**Saber Rider, and the Star Sheriffs!**

**Saber Rider, and the Star Sheriffs,**

**In the sky!**

Not Silver Surfer in disguise.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Saber Rider

Hey! I did some hunting, and I guess this is the one. The opening repeats a lot the name of the show: **[Saber Rider](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0129712/)**.

There is your guy with blue cowboy hat, a girl in pink, and a mecha with a Cowboy hat. Check the opening in [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LKxWl4PcBY4).

Here is a picture of the team for you:

[image]

And here is the mecha Ramrod:

[image]

Comment: That's the one. Thank you so much! It's been in my head for a day or so, it was driving me crazy. Turns out it wasn't a gunshot but a whip snap in the opening.  Thank you again.

Comment: @jo1storm No problem, man! I I know the feeling of freedom to finally find out what is the show stuck in the head. Haha...

Comment: It's interesting how I was completely able to forget the main character and his name. Damn brain, farting at me and laughing :)

Answer (score 1):

The show was called *Silverhawks*.  It ran from about 1986 to about 1987. http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0090520/

Comment: Sorry, that's not it. They look like Silver Surfers and there is a guy with cowboy hat, but the music is not right and the cowboy guy is not blue. And the girl is also not wearing pink as far as I can see. I'll try to clarify my question more.

Comment: Yeah, It's not Silverhawks. The opening music just sounds a LOT like Silver Surfer. Visually speaking, it is not like silver surfer. It's got more like a power rangers vibe.  Thanks for trying to help me.